# custom fields not inserting using WHMCS API

Tags: api, whmcs

I am trying to insert some extra client details using WHMCS API's 'add client'.
However the insertion takes place , but the customfields gets no effect,when I checked in WHMCS client area.I have `customfield[1],[2]...[5]` added as fields in client area.The code snippet is as follows

```
$postfields["action"] = "addclient"; 

$customfields = array(
'customfield[1]' => "ABC",
'customfield[2]' => "XYZ"
);

$postfields["customfields"] = base64_encode(serialize($customfields)
```

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

I just changed

```
$customfields = array(
'customfield[1]' => "ABC",
'customfield[2]' => "XYZ"
);

$postfields["customfields"] = base64_encode(serialize($customfields)
```

into

```
$postfields["customfield[1]"] = "ABC";
$postfields["customfield[2]"] = "XYZ";
```

Comment: Just a note that some people may find useful.  No matter what I tried I couldnt get custom fields to insert via the API when creating a new client but it did work when creating the client then updating the client straight after with the custom fields with the 'updateclient' api command.

Answer (score 1):

The following should solve the issue:

```php
$customfields = array( '1' => "ABC", '2' => "XYZ" );
$postfields["customfields"] = base64_encode(serialize($customfields)
```